# is a musk deer's musk pod in its abdomen, its back, or its bottom/rear end?

Tags: zoology

I have read/heard different things about where a musk deer stores its perfume

Some links say it stores it in its abdomen just in front of its penis.  Others say the rectum(by which I suppose they mean the backside).

A) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deer_musk  "Deer musk is a substance with a persistent odor, obtained from a gland of the male musk deer situated **in its back/rectal area**. The substance has been extensively used as a perfume fixative, incense material, and medicine, since ancient times."

B) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6CZKuSjlhI   7:40  "the fangs, but it's **the other end of the deer** that attracts more attention - the male's musk gland produces a scent that's irresistible to .. and perfume makers"

C) http://sandwalk.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/are-you-sexually-attracted-to-male-musk.html   Only the mature male Moschus produces musk. **The substance occurs in only one location on the deer's body: on its abdomen, just in front of its penis**, is a hairy pouch known as the musk gland. This sac is about the size of a golf ball. It is composed of several layers of skin, with two openings immediately above the animal's urethra.

Quite a few links agree with 'C', that it's in the abdomen near the penis. Are wikipedia and national geographic wrong for putting the musk pod in the backside?

Comment: Here's [another description of the musk sac](https://books.google.com/books?id=726qparJDBgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=%22musk%20sac%22&f=false). It mentions a musk sac that is "situated between the umbilicus and penis", as well as a caudal gland.

Comment: @AndersonGreen  I guess umbilicus is belly button. And since between the umbilicus and penis is the abdomen, it sounds like that's in agreement with  'C'  -  abdomen

Comment: does [this image](https://i.imgur.com/dyvBN9U.jpg) help? [source](https://bjsm.bmj.com/content/47/2/109)

Comment: @WhatHiFi i guess maybe the answer is the back underside of a deer has its  penis  and scrotum and still near the back but a little bit further towards the front of the penis, is the stomach.  I will see if I can get to a farm and get a picture of the underside of a deer. will be a bit of a project.